# Accurate direct distance between two points (latitude, longitude, and altitude)

Tags: geometry, distance, elevation

First of all, thanks for reading. I have Vincenty working in Excel(VBA) already, and want to do this in Excel, but this is a math question, not a coding question. By the way, I'll readily cop up front to the fact that ellipsoids are way over my head.

I'm looking to calculate accurate direct distance between two objects, given their latitude, longitude and altitude. Vincenty was an interesting start, but two issues:

(a) Vincenty is the distance along the ellipsoid, and I would need the chord length.
(b) Vincenty doesn't account for elevation, and the distance between points increases as elevation increases.

It would be easy to take Vincenty as my horizontal distance, and use the elevation difference to solve for the slope, but that doesn't seem accurate.

Maybe this should just be solving for the line between points on concentric circles (i.e. the lower elevation versus the higher elevation) except what Earth radius to use? I mean, it's an ellipsoid, so...?

My distances will typically be 10 - 40 miles, but millimeter precision is required.

Point me in the right direction? Thanks! ~Mike

Comment: I'd recommend you convert geographic coordinates to Cartesian coordinates i.e. x,y,z then get the distance and direction from there. If you need to turn the resulting direction back into compass heading and elevation, that would likely be the hardest part. I'd suggest you start with a version that assumes the earth is a sphere, and then extend that to a WGS 84 ellipsoid once you have the basics in place and find you need even more accuracy.